# Does Any() extension method handle null values?

Tags: c#, .net, list, int, extension-methods

In the below program,  `(!testlist.Any())` throws an argument null exception. Doesn't Any() extension method by default handle null values ?

What is the right approach for this ? Should a null check be added before Any() when `List<int>` is used as a parameter in a method ?

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");

            foo(null);
         }

        public static void foo(List<int> testlist)
        {
            if (!testlist.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("testlist is empty!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (!testList?.Any() ?? false) { doStuff(testList); }` Unless you want to re-throw the exception.

Comment: It "handles" null value for the collection by throwing the exception.

Comment: throws a `ArgumentNullException` if `source or predicate is null`

Comment: If I had time, I would write a lengthy answer explaining that the answer depends on the *contract* of your method, explain what a contract is and why it matters. There are lots of such answers on SO - maybe someone wants to find and link to one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should a null check be added before Any() when List is used as a
>   parameter in a method ?

Yes, that's the right approach. The method should fail fast with a meaningful message.

```
public static void foo(List<int> testlist)
{
    if(testlist == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testlist), $"{nameof(testlist)} must not be null");
    if (!testlist.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("testlist is empty!");
    }
}
```

Of course `Enumerable.Any` does not handle this for you. It might be a bug that `null` was passed to this method or it might be a viable option. **Only you know**.

The exception is also [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx):

> "`ArgumentNullException`: source is null."

If you don't want to throw it but you want to accept null, just handle this case:

```
if(testlist == null || !testlist.Any()) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("testlist is null or empty!");
}
else ....
```

Comment: Or it should not fail at all if the contract for the method says that a null `testList` is OK. I don't think that is a good solution but there could be a reason why the OP is in this situation.

Comment: The users who are consuming this method are not technical. they might still pass null values & the method may return "emptylist" in that case